# Routing conundrum with VM and bridges on Linux

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, routing, bridge

I have the following setup:

```
      Hypervisor host 1              |            Hypervisor host 2
                                     |
------------------                   |
| VM             |                   |
| 10.244.140.10  |                   |
| GW 10.244.140.1|                   |    Route to 10.244.8.0/24 
------------------                   |    goes through br1
        |                            |
 /--------------\ /-------------\    |   /-------------\  /--------------\
 |     br0      | |     br1     |    |   |     br1     |  |     br0      |
 |10.244.140.254| | 10.244.8.21 |    |   | 10.244.8.1  |  | 10.244.140.1 |
 |              | | ....        |    |   | 10.244.8.33 |  |              |
 \--------------/ \-------------/    |   \-------------/  \--------------/
        |                |           |         |                 |
       eth0             eth1------------------eth1              eth0
        |                            |                           |
        \--------------------------------------------------------/
```

Two hosts with virtual machines. Several subnets are defined: 10.244.140.0/24 on the *br0* bridges, 10.244.8.0/24 on the *br1* bridges. The *br1* bridges have several IP addresses. No netfilter rules. Netfilter policies are ACCEPT. `ip_forward` is set.

A VM is connected to *br0* on host 1. It pings 10.244.8.21, an address that is in a different subnet but resides on the same host 1. The VM's default gateway is 10.244.140.1 and resides on host 2.

**My naive expectation**: The echo request packet is sent to *br0* on host2, since *br0* has the gateway address. The packet is then routed to *br1* and back to host1.

**Reality**: The packet arrives as expected. However, **it is not routed**. On the other hand, packets sent to 10.244.8.33 arrive at *br1* on host 2, and echo replies go back.

**Where am I wrong**? And more importantly: How can I fix this?

The hypervisor hosts run OpenSuse Leaf 15 and KVM.

**EDIT**: Since I don't have enough reputation to add comments, I put answers in the question. Thanks for your concern.

***Fang***: *your packet arrives "as expected", it has passed subnet borders and thus, was routed.* Sorry, my description was incomplete. It arrives **at br0 on host 2**, in the same subnet, and is not routed further.

***Grawity***: I guess your first question is answered now.
*Which destination MAC address does the packet have* when it traverses br0 on host1?
The router's MAC, i.e the MAC of br0 on host 2. It knows it because of an ARP for which it does get a response.

Comment: You're pinging 10.244.8.21 in 10.244.8.0/24 from 10.244.140.10 in 10.244.140.0/24. If, as you say, your packet arrives "as expected", it has passed subnet borders and thus, was routed.

Comment: When you say "the packet arrives as expected", which host and which interface do you mean at that point? Also, which destination MAC address does the packet have the moment it shows up on host1's br0?

Answer (score 0):

**Reverse path filtering**.

I had known that it existed, but I didn't make the connection to my problem. RPF limits reply packets to be sent out through the receiving interface. in my case, replies would go through a different interface and are therefore blocked.

The solution is to disable reverse path filtering on both hypervisor hosts, for example

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
```

This makes hosts vulnerable to certain network attacks, but my environment is isolated from the big bad internet and I don't care.

For more information, see the `rp_filter` paragraph on the [kernel documentation page for network parmeters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt).